# What is net.rim.device.api.database.DatabaseIOException: File system error (12)

Tags: blackberry

I don't know how to fix this...

```
        URI dbURI = URI.create("file:///SDCard/Databases/MyDatabase.db");
        Database database = DatabaseFactory.open(dbURI);
```

It created DB without any problem, throws exception while trying to open DB.

Comment: using simulator or device ?Can U try URI>create("/SDCard/Databases/MyDatabases.db")

Comment: I found the problem / solution. When DB Connection is open, it can't get another Connection.  So i call below control in finally block of all DB methods:

                                If (database != null)
                                    database.close();

Comment: If you have found the solution to your problem, you should post it as an answer and accept it so that others can easily tell that a solution has been found.

Comment: I have the same problem in an app,and I was solved in the same way

Comment: Scott W, I am not allowed to answer my own question. Because I don't have enough reputation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. If I try to open a DB connection before closing the previous connection it throws this exception. So, after all DB operations I call `database.close()`

Answer (score 0):

make new folder with application name in SDCard/Databases/ and put your database in it.
After that you have to just pass database name in URI.create().

I hope it will be helpful to your .:)